# Clojure: How to determine if a nested list contains non-numeric items?

Tags: list, clojure, nested-lists

I need to write a Clojure function which takes an unevaluated arbitrarily deep nesting of lists as input, and then determines if any item in the list (not in function position) is non-numeric. This is my first time writing anything in Clojure so I am a bit confused. Here is my first attempt at making the function:

```
(defn list-eval
  [x]
  (for [lst x]
    (for [item lst]
      (if(integer? item)
        (println "")
        (println "This list contains a non-numeric value")))))
```

I tried to use a nested for-loop to iterate through each item in every nested list. Trying to test the function like so:

```
=> (list-eval (1(2 3("a" 5(3)))))
```

results in this exception:

```
ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  listeval.core/eval7976 (form-init4504441070457356195.clj:1)
```

Does the problem here lie in the code, or in how I call the function and pass an argument? In either case, how can I make this work as intended?

Comment: What should happen if a map is passed to it, either as the top level data structure or somewhere deeper? Do both its keys and values have to be checked? Also, FYI something can be "numeric" yet not an integer.

Comment: For the fun of it, here is the specter version, that gives you the non-coll/number items `(select (walker (comp not (some-fn coll? number?))) '(1(2 3("a" 5(3)))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `(1 ..)` is treated as calling a function, and `1` is a `Long`, and not a function. First you should change the nested list to `'(1(2 3("a" 5(3))))`. Next you can change your function to run recursively:

```
(defn list-eval
  [x]
  (if (list? x)
    (for [lst x] (list-eval lst))
    (if (integer? x)
      (println "")
      (println "This list contains a non-numeric value"))))
=> (list-eval '(1(2 3("a" 5(3)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool function called `tree-seq` that does all the hard work for you in traversing the structure. Use it then remove any collections, remove all numbers, and check if there is anything left.

```
(defn any-non-numbers?
  [x]
  (->> x
       (tree-seq coll? #(if (map? %) (vals %) %))
       (remove (some-fn coll? number?))
       not-empty
       boolean))
```

Examples:

```
user=> (any-non-numbers? 1)
false
user=> (any-non-numbers? [1 2])
false
user=> (any-non-numbers? [1 2 "sd"])
true
user=> (any-non-numbers? [1 2 "sd" {:x 1}])
true
user=> (any-non-numbers? [1 2 {:x 1}])
false
user=> (any-non-numbers? [1 2 {:x 1 :y "hello"}])
true
```

If you want to consider map keys as well, just change `(vals %)` to `(interleave (keys %) (vals %))`.

Answer (score 0):

#### quoting

As others have mentioned, you need to quote a list to keep it from being evaluated as
code. That's the cause of the exception you're seeing.

#### for and nesting

`for` will only descend to the nesting depth you tell it to. It is not a for loop,
as you might expect, but a sequence comprehension, like the the python list comprehension.

`(for [x xs, y ys] y)` will presume that xs is a list of lists and flatten it.
`(for [x xs, y ys, z zs] z)` Is the same but with an extra level of nesting.

To walk down to any depth, you'd usually use recursion.
(There are ways to do this iteratively, but they're more difficult to wrap your head around.)

#### side effects

You're doing side effects (printing) inside a lazy sequence. This will work at the repl,
but if you're not using the result anywhere, it won't run and cause great confusion.
It's something every new clojurian bumps into at some point.
(`doseq` is like `for`, but for side effects.)

The clojure way is to separate functions that work with values from functions that
"do stuff", like printing to the console of launching missiles, and to keep the
side effecting functions as simple as possible.

#### putting it all together

Let's make a clear problem statement: Is there a non number anywhere inside an
arbitrarily nested list? If there is, print a message saying that to the console.

In a lot of cases, when you'd use a for loop in other langs `reduce` is what you want in clojure.

```
(defn collect-nested-non-numbers
  ;; If called with one argument, call itself with empty accumulator
  ;; and that argument.
  ([form] (collect-nested-non-numbers [] form))
  ([acc x]
   (if (coll? x)
     ;; If x is a collection, use reduce to call itself on every element.
     (reduce collect-nested-non-numbers acc x)

     ;; Put x into the accumulator if it's a non-number
     (if (number? x)
       acc
       (conj acc x)))))

;; A function that ends in a question mark is (by convention) one that
;; returns a boolean.
(defn only-numbers? [form]
  (empty? (collect-nested-non-numbers form)))

;; Our function that does stuff becomes very simple.
;; Which is a good thing, cause it's difficult to test.
(defn warn-on-non-numbers [form]
  (when-not (only-numbers? form)
    (println "This list contains a non-numeric value")))
```

And that'll work. There already exists a bunch of things that'll help you walk a nested structure, though, so you don't need to do it manually.

There's the `clojure.walk` namespace that comes with clojure. It's for when you have
a nested thing and want to transform some parts of it. There's `tree-seq` which is explained
in another answer. [Specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter) is a library which is
a very powerful mini language for expressing transformations of nested structures.

Then there's my utils library [comfy](https://github.com/madstap/comfy) which contains reduce versions of the
functions in clojure.walk, for when you've got a nested thing and want to "reduce" it to a single value.

The nice thing about that is that you can use `reduced` which is like the imperative break statement, but for `reduce`. If it finds a non-number it doesn't need to keep going through the whole thing.

```
(ns foo.core
  (:require
   [madstap.comfy :as comfy]))

(defn only-numbers? [form]
  (comfy/prewalk-reduce
   (fn [ret x]
     (if (or (coll? x) (number? x))
       ret
       (reduced false)))
   true
   form))
```

Maybe by "any item in the list (not in function position)" you meant this?

```
(defn only-numbers-in-arg-position? [form]
  (comfy/prewalk-reduce
   (fn [ret x]
     (if (and (list? x) (not (every? (some-fn number? list?) (rest x))))
       (reduced false)
       ret))
   true
   form))
```